# Set the DataContext of a ComboBox in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

This is part of a WPF MVVM application. I believe the problem I am having with this is that the data context is not clear. This data grid's ItemsSource is a collection of ViewModels. This is a property in a ViewModel used to display the rest of the data. So all the data is showing up and even individual items in the SpecimentViewModel. The only thing not working is I cannot display the chosen option in the comboBox. Since I have been messing with this I cannot even see "Select Note" which is the default (Item 0). As I said, all of the other columns appear. They are all properties in each viewModel. So is my ComboBox not seeing the DataContext?

```
                <DataGrid
                ItemsSource="{Binding Specimens}"
                Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
                Background="Beige"
                FontFamily="Verdana"
                FontSize="10"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                AlternatingRowBackground="Beige"
                AlternationCount="2"
                AllowDrop="False"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                DataContext="">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TestNumber}"
                                        Header="No."
                                        Width=".05*" />

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PlyCount}"
                                        Header="Ply Count"
                                        Width=".14*" />

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PlyThickness}"
                                        Header="Ply Thickness"
                                        Width=".14*" />

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TearPerPly}"
                                        Width=".14*">

                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.SpencerDartHeading, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn
                        Header="Note"
                        Width=".14*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ResultOptions}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedNote, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

The ViewModel looks like this;

```
    private Specimen specimen;
    private ObservableCollection<string> resultOptions = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public Specimen Specimen
    {
        get
        {
            return specimen;
        }
        set
        {
            specimen = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Specimen");
        }
    }

    public string SelectedNote
    {
        get
        {
            if (specimen.ResultNote == null)
                specimen.ResultNote = "Select Note";
            return specimen.ResultNote;
        }
        set
        {
            specimen.ResultNote = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ResultOptions
    {
        get { return resultOptions; }
        set
        {
            resultOptions = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

And the Specimen Model simply has a few test properties and the ResultNote string property. So a TestViewModel has the properties for a single test, one of which is a collection of SpecimenViewModels called Specimens. Each of the SpecimenViewModels has a property which is a ResultNote. That result note is selected from a combo box which is filled with a collection of Options called ResultOptions which is in the SpeciimenViewModel. The selected value is put into the property "ResultNote."

Comment: What does the ResultOptions property return? How is this type defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate everyone's answer. Especially Kasper and Ncfuncion. They put a lot of work into the answers. Unfortunately none of them worked for me. It turns out my XAML code was fine. I finally discovered the problem was in the assembly of the data. I cannot explain why it was a problem. I was able to go back in time to when I knew it worked (thankfully I use GIT version control). I checked the code over and over and finally found a line that I changed somewhere along the way. I was certain I had debugged and seen the proper values, but they just weren't showing up in the data grid. Oh well, I got my brain back. For any one wanting to see how the working code looks here is the XAML. I skipped the other columns for brevity.

```
                <DataGrid
                ItemsSource="{Binding Specimens}"
                Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
                Background="Beige"
                FontFamily="Verdana"
                FontSize="10"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                AlternatingRowBackground="Beige"
                AlternationCount="2"
                AllowDrop="False"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                >
                <DataGrid.Columns> 
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn
                        Header="Note"
                        Width=".14*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ResultOptions}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedNote}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Note"
                        Width=".14*" 
                        SortMemberPath="SelectedNote">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ResultOptions}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValuePath="SelectedNote" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Kasper. I edited the original post to include the Specimen model and SpecimenViewModel so it would be clearer for you. Although you may not have needed that. The comboBox is filled with the options when a Specimen is created. The Collection of Specimens is in a different (parent) viewModel. So in the parent there is the Collection of Specimens (You called ObservableCollection<DataGridModel> Specimens { get; set; }) but your next line is in what you call the DataGridModel as well as the property ResultNote.

Comment: I have edited my answer according to information you provided. Also if your Specimens contain only properties that you bind to controls in another ViewModels, it should not be called ViewModel, but Model. ViewModel is a class that manages actions performed on the View, while Model is a class that holds data related properties. As far as I understand your code, your Specimens are Models, but this is not related to your question.

Comment: Thank you. Almost! The Comboboxes all have there contents and display the item at 0 ("Select Note"). So I have to figure out how to set the selected index based on the Selected Value because the ComboBox is not showing the selected value. An examination of the objects shows the property is set to the correct value, but the combobox does not change to reflect the SelectedNote. I apologiz for not giving you enough detail in the first place.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you want to achieve, so correct me if I'm wrong. Are those three points valid for you?

1). You want to be able to set SelectedItem of the ComboBox cell from your ViewModel
2.) You want to display SelectedNote as a value of the ComboBox cell
3.) You want to get both SelectedNote as a string value and a SelectedNoteIndex as an int value of your SelectedItem in your ViewModel

Comment: The combo box has the list of possible options to select from. The selected option will get saved with the rest of the data. When I select the file with the data and it is displayed on the screen, I want the previously selected string to appear as the selected value. For example; The original file opens on the screen and the datagrid shows 15 rows of information. The last column has a combo box with optional notes. The default note is "Select Note." If I had selected "My Note" before, I want to see "My Note" when the file opens. I save "My Note" with the file. Everything else works.

Answer (score 0):

In the header binding try to use `SelectedItem` property instead of `DataContext`:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.SpencerDartHeading, ..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

Like what you set for the last text column in the DataGrid, you use data binding by specifying `RelativeSource` property, you could also use such an approach to set the `ItemsSource` for your ComboBox, like this:

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn
                    Header="Note"
                    Width=".14*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.ResultOptions}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

As to `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem`, I think you should just set one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the View:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid
                ItemsSource="{Binding Specimens}"

                Background="Beige"
                FontFamily="Verdana"
                FontSize="10"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                AlternatingRowBackground="Beige"
                AlternationCount="2"
                AllowDrop="False"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TestNumber}"
                                        Header="No."
                                        Width=".05*" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PlyCount}"
                                        Header="Ply Count"
                                        Width=".14*" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PlyThickness}"
                                        Header="Ply Thickness"
                                        Width=".14*" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TearPerPly}"
                                        Width=".14*">

                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.SpencerDartHeading, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Note"
                        Width=".14*" 
                        SortMemberPath="SelectedNote">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ResultOptions}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValuePath="SelectedNote" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the ViewModel:

```
public class SpecimenViewModel
    {
        private Specimen specimen;
        private ObservableCollection<string> resultOptions = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public SpecimenViewModel(Specimen specimen)
        {           
            resultOptions.Add("Select Note");
            resultOptions.Add("Select 1");
            resultOptions.Add("Select 2");
            resultOptions.Add("Select 3");

            this.specimen = specimen;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedNote");
        }


        public Specimen Specimen
        {
            get
            {
                return specimen;
            }
            set
            {
                specimen = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Specimen");
            }
        }

        public string SelectedNote
        {
            get
            {
                if (specimen.ResultNote == null)
                    specimen.ResultNote = "Select Note";
                return specimen.ResultNote;
            }
            set
            {
                specimen.ResultNote = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> ResultOptions
        {
            get { return resultOptions; }
            set
            {
                resultOptions = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your solution resulted in empty ComboBoxes. The other columns had their data. In my original post the columns all had data, and the comboboxes had the options but the correct option was not selected even though the SelectedNote property was properly set with the correct note.

Comment: Your DataGrid itemsSource is 'Specimens'. Can you show your ViewModel where 'Specimens' are specified?

Comment: The SpecimenViewModel is shown above in my original post now. The SelectedNote is a property in the SpecimenViewModel. Specimens is a collection of SpecimenViewModels in TestResultViewModel.